# При запуске из-под wine у программы отсутствует аудио

Tags: linux, аудио, wine, pulseaudio

**Пробовал удалить pulseaudio, оставить только alsa, всё равно ничего не изменилось.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Test Sound работает-то?

Comment: @andreymal работает

Comment: Тогда что за программа?

Comment: @andreymal тестил на trinity media player

Comment: Фиг знает, как неабоненты Trinity мы вряд ли сможем воспроизвести у себя вашу проблему

Comment: @andreymal необязательно быть аббонентом

Comment: Ну не знаю, мне программа заявила ошибку авторизации и отказалась работать как-либо. Где в ней воспроизвести звук без авторизации — мне найти не удалось